# How exactly should I apporach this programming question?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

**Question**
Consider there is 4 test question in a test. 1 page consists of 1 question and it is a multiple choice. You can move forward and backward between questions using a specific command. Each page should be represented as a class and the last page is the summary of what you have picked in those questions.
Write a program that allows you to do that with OOP.

**Command** - that user can use in the program

```
start() - To start the test and the first page of the test should be given once this command run.
next_page() - To move to the next page
back_page() - To move back a page
select(int i) - Select an answer on the current page
```

I am given the above problem and I needed to write a program that works intended. Here is what I have so far. I'm free to design the program any way I wanted and there is no restriction. If my design below is completely wrong, feel free to tell me how exactly I should approach this problem.

---

Here is how my Question class look like:

```
class Question1
int answer;
void display(){
    print("This is Question1")
    print("1. Answer")
    print("2. Answer")
    print("3. Answer")
    print("You have selected:" + answer);
}
void select(int i){
  this.answer = i;
}
```

In other Question class. It looks similar but different questions and choices.

In the summary class, it will be printing out what I have chosen

```
class Summary() {
   void display(){
      print("Summary")
      print("In question 1, you've selected: " + Question1.answer);
      print("In question 2, you've selected: " + Question2.answer)
      print("In question 3, you've selected: " + Question3.answer)
      print("In question 4, you've selected: " + Question4.answerr);
    }
}
```

I have an application class. Which is like the brain of this program. It stores all the information needed to print the correct class of display() method. It keeps track of what page I am on right now. Also, I can go next page, move back a page, or select the answer on the current page. Also, I have an abstracted Page class in which each question inherited from the Page class.

```
//How exactly does the page cluster work?
            +--------+----  Page  -+---------+-----------+(This is an abstract class)
            |        |             |         |           |
     Question1     Question2   Question3 Question4  Summary (This the 5 pages, that inherited from Page class with)

class Application
int current_p; // Current position of the question.
Page p[] = new Page[5];

public Application(){//Constructor
   p[0] = new Quesion1;
   p[1] = new Quesion2;
   p[2] = new Quesion3;
   p[3] = new Quesion4;
   p[4] = new Summary;
   current_p = 1;
}
public start(){
   p[current_p].display();
}
public next(){
  current_p++;
  p[current_p].display();
}
public back(){
  current_pn--;
  p[current_p].display();
}
public select(int i){
   p[cuurent_p].select(i);// Go back to my Question class to see how select work.
   p[current_p].display();
}
```

As this is so long and it may get confused about what I am trying to do. Here is an example of output

```
Main(){
 Application a = new Application();
 a.start();
 a.select(2);
 a.next();
 a.select(1);
 a.next();
 a.next();
 a.next();
}
```

In the command line it should output something like this:

```
This is Question1
1. Answer
2. Answer
3. Answer
You have selected: 0

This is Question1
1. Answer
2. Answer
3. Answer
You have selected: 2

This is Question2
1. Answer
2. Answer
3. Answer
You have selected: 0 

This is Question2
1. Answer
2. Answer
3. Answer
You have selected: 1

This is Question3
1. Answer
2. Answer
3. Answer
You have selected: 0

This is Question4
1. Answer
2. Answer
3. Answer
You have selected: 0

Summary
In question 1, you've selected:  2
In question 2, you've selected:  1
In question 3, you've selected:  0
In question 4, you've selected:  0
```

So my problem right now is that I can't find a way to get an answer from each question and display it from the Summary class. How should I change my design or how should I do it if my design still works?

Comment: You can store the questions in a list or array, and then store the position as an integer. If the user uses the `.next()` command, increment the position and print out the item in the array at that position.

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this as follows:

- You have an `Application` class.
- You have an **abstract** `Page` class.
- You have a `QuestionPage` class which extends `Page`.
- You have a `SummaryPage` class which also extends `Page`.
- You have a `QuestionOption` class.

`Application` should have a `List<Page>` of all of the pages you want.

`Page` should have a `display()` method, or similar, to achieve the functionality you want for each diverse page.

It sorta defeats the point of OOP to make a separate class for each question, so I would instantiate each question as a new `QuestionPage`. Therefore, to differentiate each question, you'd need to have a constructor with arguments for the questions, such as:

```java
// QuestionPage.java (extends Page)
private final QuestionOption questionOptionOne;
private final QuestionOption questionOptionTwo;
private final QuestionOption questionOptionThree;
private QuestionOption inputAnswer;

public QuestionPage(QuestionOption questionOne, QuestionOption questionTwo, QuestionOption questionThree){
    this.questionOptionOne = questionOptionOne;
    this.questionOptionTwo= questionOptionTwo;
    this.questionOptionThree= questionOptionThree;
}

public void setInputAnswer(QuestionOption inputAnswer) {
    this.inputAnswer = inputAnswer;
}

//QuestionOption.java
private final String description;

public QuestionOption(String description) {
    this.description = desctription;
}
```

When you construct the `Application` class, you should input the aforementioned `List<Page>`. It should keep a count (`pageNumber`) of which `Page` you are on. You should then be able to call a `nextPage()` method, which increments the `pageNumber` and redisplays the `Page`.

When they answer, you'd call `setInputAnswer` to store their answer.

The `SummaryPage` would then iterate through all of the `QuestionPage`s and display their `inputAnswers`

Overall, I'd be careful to try to follow OOP techniques - don't make a new class if you already have one to do that job. Also, in terms of Java, I'd personally use an interface for each `Page` (instead of an abstract class), with a `displayOptions` method, for the reason that you aren't doing the exact same thing on any two `Page`s, so there's no functionality to be shared and benefitted from in an abstract class. That's just my preference, though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Spectric What do you mean? I've been around for a while... just haven't answered many questions until now... :)

Comment: Woopsie. I was judging by your reputation. My mistake :P